# Kotlin failed to download

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

Yesterday I reinstalled my Android Studio and tried to add Kotlin plugin in preferences, but there was no callback afterwards.

[image]

Progress bar finished it work and I caught this error.

Is it connected with last Android Studio update?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a problem with the download server. Please try again.

Comment: @AndreyBreslav still causes the problem. Hope, tomorrow will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try to download latest version of plugin directly from [Kotlin Download plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954?pr=androidstudio) and install it manually from disk:

Settings > Plugins > Install plugin from disk... and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me is

File< Manage IDE settings < Restore default settings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).